# Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time

Tags: beginner, c

Continuing to slowly progress through `The C Programming Language` by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

The code I came up with below is for `Exercise 1-19 - Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time`.

Feedback is much appreciated.

```c
// Exercise 1-19. Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s.
// Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

#include <stdio.h>

void reverseLine(char *s);

void reverseLine(char *s) {
    int count;
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    for (int j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        putchar(s[j -1]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    int ch, charCount;
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    charCount = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (charCount >= BUFSIZ - 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Overly long line ignored.\n");
            while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
                ;
            }
            line[charCount] = ch;
            charCount = 0;
            continue;
        }
        line[charCount++] = ch;
        if (ch == '\n') {
            line[charCount++] = '\0';
            reverseLine(line);
            charCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: What you can do is write a follow up question with a link back to this question with your new improved code.

Comment: Wow, that is an old book. Don't expect everything in it to be up-to-date with current programming practices.

Comment: Thanks, @fishinear - Although it is old, I think it's a terrific book, especially for someone like myself who has a grasp on the basics of programming, albeit not at a deep level. The words on the pages flowed from two unbelievable minds. I owe it to myself to read their words in this book. Plus, the exercises are proving to be extraordinarily valuable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation is not what the exercise asked for. It asked for a function that reverses a string (implied: in-place), and separately, I/O to read and print lines using that function. What it did not ask for is a function that immediately prints the reverse of the string.

Your declaration of `reverseLine` is redundant so delete it; only the definition is needed.

In your current intepretation, `s` should be a `const char *s` since it isn't mutated, but again, the problem asks for in-place mutation.

Rather than ignoring long lines, just truncate them.

`reverseLine` should be `static`.

C allows for `int main` to omit the `return`, but that's a bad idea. Write the `return`.

In-predicate mutation, i.e. `while ((ch = getchar())`, is common but an anti-pattern. Do not mutate your variables on the inside of predicates.

`reverseLine` has re-implemented `strlen`. Don't do that; just call `strlen`.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight regarding the problem being implied in-place reverse versus immediately printing the reverse of the string. I will get on this.

so to be clear, in place would mean `foo bar` would become `oof rab`, right?

Comment: Sounds tricky. So I wouldn't be allowed to use a temporary storage container like `char line[BUFSIZ]`?

Comment: You shouldn't need it. Think more on an algorithm that is able to swap characters within a single array.

Comment: Ok, will work on this and update the code when complete.

Comment: Surely "foo bar" should become "rab oof"? Reverse whole string. Reversing individual words is a step further, perhaps.

Comment: You need just a single additional char for the swap .

Comment: @iamericfletcher in-place means that the function works like this: `char s[8] = "foo bar"; reverse(s); printf("%s", s);` prints `rab oof`. In-place means that the original string, passed to the function, gets overwritten with the new reversed string. It does not mean that each space-separated word in the string should be reversed on its own and then concatenated in original order

Comment: @iamericfletcher (works like `char s[8] = "foo bar"; reverse(s); printf("%s", s);`, which is in-place, as opposed to `char s[8] = "foo bar"; char *result = reverse(s); printf("%s", result);` where `s` still refers to its original value at the end.)

Comment: Please post your edit in a new question

Comment: “Implied: in-place” was probably true in the 1970s, but if you tried to do that today, it would break on UTF-8 input, or Unicode combining characters. That said, figuring out grapheme boundaries is something a newbie’s not going to be able to do using only the building blocks in *K&R*.

Comment: Even so, a programmer does need to be aware that real-world strings in this century contain multi-byte characters, but a lot of older code assumes they don’t. UTF-8 is designed so that *most* of that code will still work anyway, but reversing the bytes of a string is one that will break it.

Answer (score 4):

The main program can be simplified by using a function you probably haven't read about yet called [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). This function reads a line of text at a time. The variable `line` will contain the new line after the function has been called; you would need to remove the newline before you reverse the input.

```
int main() {
    char line[BUFSIZ];

    while (fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (line[0]) {
            reverseLine(line);
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to go with what I've learned thus far, but I'm sure it's only a matter of time before this function is introduced.

Answer (score 4):

Independent of whether the function `reverseString` as written is doing what it should, it has an off-by-one error. In the loop `putchar`ing the characters of the input string in reverse order,

```
for (int j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    putchar(s[j - 1]);
}
```

consider that for any `count` > 0, the last iteration will execute with `j` equal to 0, causing `s[-1]` to be accessed, which is out-of-bounds. The argument to `putchar` should be just `s[j]`. Note also that even with this correction, your loop would fail to terminate if `j` were an unsigned type (due to underflow). A correct version of this loop that works for both signed and unsigned loop indexes is

```
for (int j = count; j > 0; ) {
    putchar(s[--j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Much focus on how to read a *line*, yet the coding goal was more on

> Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s.

- OP's `reverseLine()` is not too bad, yet the stated goal does not include printing.
- Strings are rarely, yet could be longer than `INT_MAX`.  To handle all *strings* use `size_t count` for determining string length.  Alternatively, simply use an end pointer.

```
    void reverseLine(char *s) {
      // for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      //  count++;
      //}
      char *endptr = s;
      while (*endptr) {
        endptr++;
      }
      // endptr now points to the string's null character.

      // walk the start and end pointers together until they meet.
      while (s < endptr) {
        endptr--; 
        char t = *endptr;
        *endptr = *s;
        *s = t;
        s++;
      }
    }
```

Often it is useful to consider the 0 length case as in  `reverseLine("")`.  OP's code does that OK with `int`, yet if `size_t` (an *unsigned* type), it would have trouble when `count == 0` and `j = count - 1`.  Instead test for `> 0`, and then decrement.

```
// for (int j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
for (size_t j = count; j > 0; ) {
    j--; // add
    putchar(s[j -1]);
```

`reverseLine()` will now reverse a string, as was the coding goal.
Now for the next goal.

> Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

To reverse the input, OP's code is OK, yet `++` not needed in `charCount++`.  Also, since a revised `reverseLine()` only reverses the string and not print it, we should print the result.

```
    if (ch == '\n') {
        //line[charCount++] = '\0';
        line[charCount] = '\0';
        reverseLine(line);
        puts(line); // add
        charCount = 0;
```

**The *last* line**

Under various conditions, the last *line* before end-of-file might not end with a `'\n'`.  So it makes sense after the `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {` to test for a rump line.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  ...
}

if (charCount > 0) {
  line[charCount] = '\0';
  reverseLine(line);
  puts(line); // Add if reverseLine() does not print.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your edification, here's a relatively efficient program which fits the exercise and imposes no specific limit in line length nor in number of lines.

A few notes:

1. The program assumes Linux-style line endings (aka LF, not CRLF).
2. The program's efficiency could be improved by calling `fgets` directly on `string.data`.

   - But to avoid allocation in the common case, it would make `String` slightly more complicated.
3. The program uses `//` instead of `/**/` for comments, this is not strictly compliant, but much easier.
4. The program has been compiled cleanly with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, but has not been tested.

Without further ado [and on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3ozh8z8j4:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//  In-place reverses the string `s` of length `length`.
static void reverse(char* s, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i) {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[length - 1 - i];
        s[length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}

struct String {
    //  NUL-terminated, if non-NULL.
    char* data;
    //  Length exclusive of NUL-terminator.
    size_t length;
    //  Allocated size of the `data`.
    size_t capacity;
};

//  Increase the capacity of `this->data` to be able to fit at least `extra` characters.
static void str_grow(struct String* this, size_t extra) {
    size_t new_capacity = this->capacity > 0 ? this->capacity * 2 : BUFSIZ * 2;

    while (extra > new_capacity - this->length) {
        new_capacity *= 2;
    }

    this->data = this->capacity == 0 ? malloc(new_capacity) : realloc(this->data, new_capacity);

    if (this->data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    this->capacity = new_capacity;
}

//  Appends the first `length` characters of `s` to `this`.
static void str_append(struct String* this, char const* s, size_t length) {
    if (length > this->capacity - this->length) {
        str_grow(this, length);
    }

    memcpy(this->data + this->length, s, length);
    this->length += length;
    this->data[this->length] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    struct String string = {};

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        size_t read = strlen(buffer);
        assert(read > 0 && "fgets returns either when the input is exhausted, the buffer is full, or when \n is encountered");

        //  Accumulate into heap-allocated buffer if the line is incomplete, and keep reading.
        if (read != BUFSIZ - 1 && buffer[read - 1] != '\n') {
            str_append(&string, buffer, read);
            continue;
        }

        //  Trim the newline character as it shouldn't be reversed.
        //  Portability note: assumes end of lines are LF only, on Windows they may be CRLF instead.
        if (buffer[read - 1] == '\n') {
            buffer[read - 1] = '\0';
            read -= 1;
        }

        //  Speed up common case of short lines by avoiding the copy to `string.data`.
        //  Also avoids memory allocations altogether if all lines are short.
        if (string.length == 0) {
            reverse(buffer, read);

            printf("%s\n", buffer);

            continue;
        }

        str_append(&string, buffer, read);

        reverse(string.data, string.length);

        printf("%s\n", string.data);

        //  Reset string length after use, next read will be a new line.
        string.length = 0;
    }

    free(string.data);
}
```

Comment: Wow - there is a lot to unpack in this implementation! Memory management, structs, etc. Thank you for this - lots to learn!

Comment: @iamericfletcher: Yes, not really a beginner's implementation, but hopefully it can help you in your journey :)

Comment: Corner case: `fgets()` and potentially reading a _null character_, as the first character leads triggering the assert.  In production code, leads to UB with `buffer[read - 1]`.  Maybe `if (read == 0) continue;`?

Comment: The `"\n"` vs. `"\r\n"` is a valid concern, yet more a compiler/shell issue than an OS one.  Could use `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")]` to find potential line endings.

Comment: Rather than double the buffer size, consider `new_size = old_size*2 + 1`.  This nicely handle the `old_size==0` case and allows growth up to `SIZE_MAX`, rather than half that.

Comment: Curious with the concern about [stack overflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282586/write-a-function-reverses-that-reverses-the-character-string-s-use-it-to-writ/282598?noredirect=1#comment560268_282598), yet this code likewise does not handle an out-of-memory.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Thanks for the review. With regard to a NUL character that's interesting. I'm not quite sure how to handle it, honestly. Filling `buffer` with non-NUL characters before calling `fgets`, then looking for a `NUL` from the end would work... but it seems we're getting far off into the weeds. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Since the memory allocation is only ever used if more than `BUFSIZ - 1` characters are read, the buffer requires at least `BUFSIZ + 1` bytes anyway, hence why the starting value is `BUFSIZ * 2`. Your scheme doesn't allow growing to `SIZE_MAX` either, did you mean `- 1` rather than `+ 1`? In any case, I'd expect the program to run out of memory prior to that happening.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: First, stack overflow is a much more likely occurrence. FreeBSD only has 1MB of stack, for example. Second, detecting out-of-memory is actually... problematic. By default, Linux uses overcommit, so that the process gets a valid pointer from `malloc`, and then is killed on attempting to use it if Linux fails to find actual RAM to back it up. As such, I've grown used not to check for NULL from `malloc` and `realloc`. Arguably not a very good example... I'll add a check.

Comment: Memory scaling was for 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 2x+1, so in your case staring at `BUFSIZ - 1` which is likely to be another [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html).

Comment: Corner:  When the last line of input does not include a `'\n'` (e.g. re-directed input from a file), that line is not reversed nor printed as "fgets returns either when the buffer is full, or when \n is encountered" only identifies 2 of at least 3 reasons `fgets()` returns non-`NULL`.

Comment: This post is totally missing the point.  1. It doesn't even try to review the OP's code.  2. The code given is too complex for a beginner.  3. The code itself is a bad example of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Corner case fixed, well spotted.

Comment: @FlorianF: I'll disagree on missing the point, I think that giving the OP examples of how to achieve the task without the limitations the OP is bumping in will help them grow. And yes, that means the code is too complex for a complete beginner, that's normal, you don't grow reading code at your level, you grow reading code at the next level. As for a bad example of reinventing the wheel, if you have better, please do propose.

Answer (score -2):

> Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time

OP's code has a line length of `BUFSIZ`.
Alternative, use recursion, without a line length limit - at least until stack depth is reached.

```
static int reverse_helper(void) {
  int ch = getchar();
  if (ch != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    int ch2 = reverse_helper();
    putchar(ch);
    ch = ch2;
  }
  return ch;
}

int reverse(void) {
  int ch = reverse_helper();
  if (ch == '\n') {
    putchar(ch);
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  return ch;
}

int main(void) {
  while (reverse() != EOF)
    ;
}
```

Comment: No line limit perhaps, but definitely _lines_ limit. A too large number of lines will lead to stack overflow. With function stack frames typically being 16 bytes aligned, I'd expect this function to cause a stack overflow with as few as 700K lines on FreeBSD (1MB stack).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Concern about stack overflow is valid (I think the math is off, perhaps you meant 70,000) - comment added about that, yet  it is the other way around.  The stack unwinds with each line (`'\n'` or `EOF`), so any stack concern is with the line length, not the number of lines.  The number of lines remains unlimited.  Code did have a problem with printing the `'\n'` before the _line_ and has been rectified.